# bash - remove first 3 characters and last 1 character from all mp3 files in all subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash

in base directory i have folders like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
110
```

so in each of them i  have files like

```
  0010011.mp3  0010031.mp3  0010051.mp3  0010071.mp3  0010021.mp3  0010041.mp3  0010061.mp3
```

so i want to remove first 3 characters and last 1 character  so files will look like this

```
 001.mp3   003.mp3   005.mp3   007.mp3   002.mp3   004.mp3  006.mp3
```

i tried this

```
for file in ??????*; do echo mv $file `echo $file | cut -c4-`; done
```

also this is not working in subdirectories it is just if files are in base directory

Answer (score 0):

If you're got `rename` (sometimes known as `prename`) you can do this in one command:

```
rename -n 's!(.*/)...(.*).(\.mp3)!$1$2$3!' */?????*.mp3
```

Alternatively you can loop through the files:

```
for f in */?????*.mp3
do
    echo mv -v "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's!(.*/)...(.*).(\.mp3)!\1\2\3!')"
done
```

In the first instance remove `-n` (or replace it with `-v`) to make it perform the work. In the second instance remove the first `echo` to allow it to apply the changes.

Comment: output of second command is 
mv -v *.mp3 p3.mp3

Comment: i need to run command in parent directory and it should work for all subdirectories

Comment: @arpa answer updated to run from the root of your folders.

Comment: for f in */*.mp3; do echo mv -v "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's!(.*/)...(.*).(\.mp3)!\1\2\3!')"; done    i get  -bash: !: event not found

Answer (score 0):

> I would not advise just collecting all files that match *.mp3 
>   and then trimming the file names.  You MAY want to run this same 
>   script AGAIN later (like next week) and it should NOT try to 
>   rename the same files a second time, making them even shorter
>   and have naming conflicts.
>
> Your example file names seem to be **001xyz1.mp3** and you want **xyz.mp3**

```
     KEEP_DIR=$PWD 
     cd /your/music/base_dir        # sub-dirs holding .mp3

     RCOUNT=0 ; SKIP=0 ; FCC=0


 for FFF in */001???1.mp3    
     do
     LOC="$(dirname $FFF)"   
     BAS="$(basename $FFF)"
     TRIM1="${BAS#1.mp3}"     #could use ${BAS:4:3}
     NEWF="$LOC/${TRIM1%001}.mp3"
     if [ -e "$NEWF" ] ; then
        echo "#-- File $NEWF already exists, not renaming $FFF"
        SKIP=$((SKIP+1))
     else
        mv $FFF $NEWF
        MCOUNT=$((MCOUNT+1))
     fi
     FCC=$((FCC+1))
 done

 echo "Renamed $MCOUNT mp3 files, of $FCC found. (Skipped $SKIP)"
 cd $KEEP_DIR

 #--[eof]
```

Comment: Don't forget to double quote `"$variables"` when you use them

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sed` to create one `mv` command line for each mp3 with a 7 characters long basename:

```
$ find . -name "???????.mp3" | sed 's/\(.*\)\(...\)\(...\)\(.\)\(\.mp3\)/mv \1\2\3\4\5 \1\3\5/'
```

After reviewing the output you can redirect it into a file and execute.